# Imagemagick command to get image metadata size

Tags: imagemagick

Is there any imagemagick command to return image metadata size? I want to get specifically metadata size embedded to image.

Answer (score 0):

By size do you mean file size or image dimensions. The former is

`convert image -format "%b" info:`

The latter is

`convert image -format "%wx%h" info:`

See https://imagemagick.org/script/escape.php

Comment: By size I mean metadata size. For example, xmp , exif , etc  data of image. I have a requirement to get size of metadata of image. Is it possible to get that using imagemagick or any other tool?

Comment: Get the file size with the meta data. Then get the file size without the meta data using -strip in the command. The compute the difference.